# Unable to upload .xml file to a new table in MS Access using vba

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, import

I am trying to have an xml file import to a new table in Access using VBA.

So far the code I have pulls the data from an API and saves it as an xml file. The problem is that when i am trying to import that file into a new Access table I get the Run-Time error ***'-2146697203 (800c000d)': Method 'ImportXML' of object '_Application' failed.***

So far the code I have is;

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60, myurl As String, MyOutput As String

myurl = "http://10.74.18.2:8000/service=46&ticket_number=RQTASK1381986&xml=true"
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.send

   MyOutput = Mid(xmlhttp.responseText, 5)


Open "C:/Users/los07/Documents/test.xml" For Output As #1
Print #1, MyOutput

Application.ImportXML MyOutput, acStructureAndData

End Sub
```

`
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the file name in the method. The issue you face is attempting to pass the text value of the XML *MyOutput* and not the actual saved file which [Application.ImportXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823157.aspx) expects:

```vb
Application.ImportXML "C:\Users\los07\Documents\test.xml", acStructureAndData
```

Also, consider saving the XML content using a MSXML DOM object, specifically its [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769(v=vs.85).aspx) method. Text file dumps may affect encoding of content as Windows text files default content to *ANSI* and may not retain *UTF*, *ISO*, etc. encodings. Recall XMLs are not quite text files but special markup documents.

```vb
Private Sub Command2_Click()    
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60, xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim myurl As String, MyOutput As String, xmlFile as String

    myurl = "http://10.74.18.2:8000/service=46&ticket_number=RQTASK1381986&xml=true"
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
    xmlhttp.send

    MyOutput = Mid(xmlhttp.responseText, 5)
    xmlFile = "C:\Users\los07\Documents\test.xml"
    xmlDoc.Save xmlFile

    Application.ImportXML xmlFile, acStructureAndData

    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. There was also an error as the description column was over 255 characters and exceeded the limit. This column was not needed so I had to remove it. 
Got the import working by saving as a file, reopening it and deleting the node which was over 255 characters, saving it as a new file and uploading the new file.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60, myurl As String, MyOutput As String

myurl = "http://10.74.18.2:8000/service=46&ticket_number=RQTASK1381986&xml=true"
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.send


 MyOutput = Mid(xmlhttp.responseText, 5)
    'takes out first 4 charachters


Open "\\livoffice04\CRM\SkyCRM\Data Team\Working Docs\Lee Osborne\test.xml" For Output As #1
Print #1, MyOutput
Close #1
    'Opens xml and saves as xml document called "test.xml" then closes the document


Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmldoc.Load "test.xml"
    'Opens xml document


Set nNode = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("//spark/description")
    'Finds description node

nNode.Text = ""
    'Deletes text in the selected node



strResult = xmldoc.Save("test1.xml")
    'Saves the xml document with the new settings and as a new file called "test1.xml".


Application.ImportXML "\\livoffice04\CRM\SkyCRM\Data Team\Working Docs\Lee Osborne\test1.xml", acAppendData
    'Imports the data from test1.xml to a table called "spark"


End Sub
```

Thanks!